# Java OptionPane displays first. Need to launch after program is launched

Tags: java

```
Object[] options = { "option 1", "option2",
                    "option 3" };
            result = JOptionPane
                    .showOptionDialog(this,
                            "Welcome! ","Welcome Message",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,
                            options[0]);
```

I Would like to show this JOptionPane after program is launched. But even if i do it at the end of constructor its invokes first before other components. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: where have you defined your optionpane? is that within constructor?

Comment: I have tried different places in program, end of constructor, last method called by constructor.

Comment: And where's exactly you want to display it? After which code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Swing UIs, you can put the code inside `windowOpened` event of the `JFrame` or `JDialog`.

```
public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
    // your JOptionPane
}
```

Then your JOptionPane will be shown after the Window becomes visible. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, worked.
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
               // optionPane here
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are calling this prior to the call to "setVisible(true)" on the rest of your application.

I would recommend you take a look at "SwingUtilities.invokeLater()"

to ensure that you code option pane is invoked at a "Later" time on the EDT.